# Remove class with jquery from LI

Tags: jquery

This adds the class to a li.  When another li is clicked it also adds the class current. But now i have two current.  You'll notice below im trying to remove the class current from the li which was initially current.

```
var
$tabs = $('.promo-tabs li'),
$panes = $('.promo-panes > div');

$tabs.click(function(){
  $(this).addClass('current')
  $(this).parent().siblings().find('li').removeClass('current');
  $panes.eq($tabs.index(this)).fadeIn().siblings().hide();
  return false;
});

 //Init Promo Tabs
$tabs.first().click();
```

Any ideas on how to tweak this line so the class is removed once another li is clicked would be great

```
  $(this).parent().siblings().find('li').removeClass('current');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just

```
$tabs.removeClass('current')
```

placed *before*

```
$(this).addClass('current')
```

? In other words, just get rid of "current" from all the `<li>` elements, and then add it to the one that's been clicked.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
$tabs.click(function(){
  $tabs.removeClass('current');      
  $(this).addClass('current')
  $panes.eq($tabs.index(this)).fadeIn().siblings().hide();
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to your question is that this

```
$(this).parent().siblings().find('li').removeClass('current');
```

Checks for li tags under the siblings of the parent.  Either of these should work

```
$(this).siblings().removeClass('current');
$(this).parent().find('li').removeClass('current');
```

But I think the most efficient solution would be

```
$(this).parent().find('li.current').removeClass('current');
$(this).addClass('current');
```